# Function to return the function name and line

Tags: python

You can get the function name and line with `sys._getframe().f_code.co_name` and `sys._getframe().f_lineno`.

I'd like a wrapper around these (awkward) values, something like:

```
def fn():    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
def line():  return sys._getframe().f_lineno
```

but that doesn't work.

For example, the following code

```
import sys

def fn():    return sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
def line():  return sys._getframe().f_lineno

def main():
  print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, fn())
  print(sys._getframe().f_lineno,       line())

main()
```

should return

```
main main
8 8
```

but instead it returns

```
main fn
8 4
```

How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Why would fn() return ```main``` when ```sys._getframe().f_code.co_name``` points to its own frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out you can do it just relying on `sys`, by passing parameter `1` to `sys._getframe` to get the frame below the current one `fn`. According to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys._getframe):

> sys._getframe([depth])
> Return a frame object from the call stack. If optional integer depth is given, return the frame object that many calls below the top of the stack. If that is deeper than the call stack, ValueError is raised. The default for depth is zero, returning the frame at the top of the call stack.

Your code will look like this:

```
import sys

def fn():    return sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_name
def line():  return sys._getframe(1).f_lineno

def main():
  print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, fn())
  print(sys._getframe().f_lineno,       line())

main()
```

Output

```
main main
8 8
```

---

##### Second way:

`sys._getframe().f_code.co_name` will return the current function, which is always `fn`. To get the frame below the current one, use `traceback`:

```
import sys
import inspect

def fn(): return inspect.stack()[-2].function
def line(): return inspect.stack()[-2].lineno

def main():
    print(sys._getframe().f_code.co_name, fn())
    print(sys._getframe().f_lineno,       line())

main()
```

Output

```
main main
9 9
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I wonder if it's possible to do the same from `sys`, without the need for `inspect`?

Comment: @étale-cohomology Turns out that's possible. Check the answer I added how.

Comment: You're indeed a rare breed. Such a helpful guy, reminds me of the older days of the internet...